# Is there a way to determine how much the total disk usage of a directory will change after calling rsync?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I'm working on setting up automatic incremental backups for a system with rsync, using a method similar to `rsnapshot`. I'd like to know whether or not the backup disk has enough space to fit a new snapshot before attempting to copy it.

In this case, rsync will be synchronizing a directory, so it may be copying in new files, copying over existing files whose size has changed, removing files, adding or removing directories, or adding and removing links (including both symlinks and hard links) on the destination. So the change in total disk space after the operation could increase or decrease by practically any amount.

Is there any way to figure out how much space the operation will require?

Comment: `Is there any way to figure out how much space the operation will require?` Note that this might not be the same size as the disk usage change at the end, as *each* of the replacing files will be fully written first before the one it replaces is deleted (at least that's the default practice). So this size requirement could be the biggest file that would be written, while the disk usage change could be nearly zero.

Comment: @TomYan That's a good point. I'll be sure to calculate the amount of space required for the operation to be the difference in disk usage after the operation (if it's positive) plus the size of the largest file involved in the operation.

Answer (score -2):

Note that even if you knew the amount of data that will be sync'ed,
there are cases where this wouldn't translate byte-for-byte to the target.
For example, if your destination filesystem is encrypted.

That said, I think that the command you're looking for is :

```
rsync -an --stats sourcedir/ destdir/
```

Where:

- `-a` : archive meta-option
- `-n` : dry run

The particular stats you need to examine are the following:

- Total file size : (given in bytes)
- Total transferred file size : (also in bytes, this is the changed data to be transferred)

To get an exact answer for the calculated sizes before and after,
this can be done with two rsync dry runs:

- one as above,
- one from the destination folder to a dummy empty folder.

The difference between the two numbers is the answer.

In the following example, folder `d1` contains `file1.txt` of
11 bytes, folder `d2` contains `file2.txt` of 6 bytes, while
folder `d3` is empty.
The rsync of d2 to d3 gives Total file size of 6 bytes,
the rsync of d1 to d2 gives 11 bytes.
Final answer : 6 bytes will become 11 bytes.

```sh
$ mkdir d1 d2 d3
$ echo 12345 >d2/file2.txt
$ echo 1234567890 >d1/file1.txt
$ rsync -an --stats d2/ d3/

Number of files: 2 (reg: 1, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 1 (reg: 1)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 1
Total file size: 6 bytes               <=== current size
Total transferred file size: 6 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 86
Total bytes received: 22

sent 86 bytes  received 22 bytes  216.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.06 (DRY RUN)

$ rsync -an --stats --delete d1/ d2/

Number of files: 2 (reg: 1, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 1 (reg: 1)
Number of deleted files: 1 (reg: 1)
Number of regular files transferred: 1
Total file size: 11 bytes              <=== future size
Total transferred file size: 11 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 84
Total bytes received: 38

sent 84 bytes  received 38 bytes  244.00 bytes/sec
total size is 11  speedup is 0.09 (DRY RUN)
```

As for the imperfect size calculations of rsync as regarding
hard links, your only other option is to run rsync in verbose mode
and parse its output yourself.

References :

- [rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)
- [Using rsync to find the size of changed data between two directories](https://kristau.net/blog/20/).

Comment: This answers "how much data will be changed", not "how much disk usage will be changed". When a file is overwritten / replaced with one that has the same size, there could be no change in the disk usage.

Comment: @TomYan: "Total file size" is the total size on the disk of the data, transferred or not transferred (optimized). This gives the future size of the destination folder (subject to my opening paragraph and your comment below the post).

Comment: So? How did that change the fact that your answer essentially answered nothing? Basically you are saying "so I know this stat give you two numbers, one of them is relevant to the answer you want, and one of them is irrelevant and I don't know why I even asked you to examine it".

Comment: @harrymc Neither "total file size" or "total transferred file size" are usable for this purpose. Neither take into account a) files being deleted on the destination, or b) files being replaced on the destination. For example, "total file size" will report a size of 1 MB if a 1 MB file overwrites another 1 MB file, even though the total amount of usage on disk did not change after the operation is over.

Comment: I think you're missing the difference between "Total" and "Transferred". In my example above there are two files of 2K each to sync. One is identical and the other not. The Total size is 4K, which is what all two files will take up on the target. The Transferred is 2K, which allows to estimate the transfer time. "Total" is the size of the files that are considered for transfer, and which will reside on the target, which is exact if extraneous files are to be deleted. Without deletion the situation is more complicated indeed.

Comment: @harrymc I meant to say "total transferred" in my last comment. Nonetheless there's a very simple example that demonstrates that using `--stats` simply doesn't provide the info I need: syncing a source folder with a single 1K file on to a destination folder with a differently named 1K file while using `--delete`. After the sync, the difference in total space used on disk is 0 bytes as one file is deleted and one is copied, but both "Total file size" and "Total transferred file size" both report 1K.

Comment: @BriBri: That means that 0 more space is required - the old equals the new. If this isn't the number you're looking for, please precise what is the right number in your above example. [Remark: a smart sync program usually does deletes before copies, since otherwise there might not be enough space on the target disk for the copy (I've discussed this in the past with one such author). Therefore the comment by Tom Yan on your post might be wrong.]

Comment: @harrymc I don't believe you're correct. I just set up another example where the source folder contains a single 1K file, and the destination folder contains a 768 byte file that's not included in the source and will be deleted. Both "Total file size" and "Total transferred file size" still both report 1024 bytes, as a 1K file will be transferred but they *do not* take into account the deleted file. There is no way to glean from the statistics that the disk usage increased by 256 bytes.

Comment: To get the answer that 768 will become 1024 can be done with two rsync dry runs: one as above and one from the destination folder to a dummy empty folder. The difference between the two numbers is your number. I added this to my answer.

Comment: @harrymc Are you actually trying out your suggestions to make sure they work? I did as you suggested using the same example as before (with the source containing a 1024 byte file and the destination containing a 768 byte file that will be deleted) and, once again, both dry runs have 1024 as the value for both "Total file size" and "Total transferred file size". Again, I reiterate, the statistics don't take into account deleted files, so rsyncing into an empty dummy folder doesn't provide any more information.

Comment: The rsync stats are byte-oriented, while the numbers you see with some other utilities may be derived from the allocated sectors. A file of 768 bytes never takes that much space on the disk, since if the sector size is 512 bytes, then it will take up 2 sectors or 1024 bytes in all. With 4K sectors it will take up 4K. It all depends on the utility you use. As the remark in my first paragraph, with rsync you only get an approximate number. Allocated disk space of the same files will change when copying them between disks with different sector sizes.

Comment: @harrymc Sector sizes are irrelevant to my point. The `--stats` option in rsync simply doesn't work the way you claim it does. See the following for an example of what I mean, taken directly from my terminal: https://pastebin.com/dnQp0uLD The number I'm looking for there is 3145728 bytes, the amount that the drive's used space has increased. It is not derivable from the stats. Please suggest a different method.

Comment: I have added an example to my answer. The example is trivial, but demonstrates the idea. I hate it when correct answers are downvoted!

Comment: @harrymc I don't like it when correct answers get downvoted too, but I simply do not think your answer is correct! I tried to get useful info out of `--stats` before asking this question and could not do it. "Total file size" doesn't take into account hard links, and will report the wrong size when copying a directory with them. "Total transferred file size" does take into account hard links, but you can't use that to determine the change in disk usage. Here's an example of this in action: https://pastebin.com/kztbzzRp

Comment: This is what rsync does, but I see that you're not satisfied with its handling of hard links. As you need rsync, as only it knows what it will do, your only other option is to run rsync in verbose mode and parse its output yourself.